# Jenkins (Hudson) - Managing dependencies between parallel builds

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, ivy, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

Using Jenkins or Hudson I would like to create a pipeline of builds with fork and join points, for example:

```
     job A
    /      \
 job B    job C
   |        |
 job D      |
    \      /
     job E
```

I would like to create arbitrary [series-parallel graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph) like this and leave Jenkins the scheduling freedom to execute B/D and C in parallel whenever a slave is available.

The [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) immediately joins after B has executed. The Build Pipeline Plugin does not support fork/join points. Not sure if this is possible with the Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin (or deprecated Locks & Latches Plugin); if so I could not figure out how. One solution could be to specify build dependencies with Apache Ivy and use the Ivy Plugin. However, my jobs are all Makefile C/C++/shell script jobs and I have no experience with Ivy to verify if this is possible.

What is the best way to specify parallel jobs and their dependencies in Jenkins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) that meets this very need.  It defines a DSL for specifying parallel jobs. Your example might be written like this:

```
build("job A")
parallel (
    {
        build("job B")
        build("job D")
    },
    {
        build("job C")
    }
)
build("job E")
```

I just found it and it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is one solution that might work for you. It requires that all builds start with a single Job and end with a definite series of jobs at the end of each chain; in your diagram, "job A" would be the starting job, jobs C and D would be the terminating jobs.

Have Job A create a fingerprinted file.  Job A can then start multiple chains of builds, B/D and C in this example.  Also on Job A, add a promotion via the [Promotions Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin), whose criteria is the successful completion of the successive  jobs - in this case, C and D.  As part of the promotion, include a trigger of the final job, in your case Job E.  This can be done with the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).  Then, make sure that each of the jobs you list in the promotion criteria also fingerprint the same file and get the same fingerprint; I use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to ensure I get the exact same file each time.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried the combination of the Promotions Plugin with the Parameterized Trigger. I'll give it a shot. Already using the Copy Artifact Plugin with fingerprinting.

Comment: Works like a charm. The fingerprinting is required to mark job E as a downstream job of A. I did not realize the fingerprinting could be used for that. Highly appreciated.